# Brauer characters of finite simple group $E_8(5)$

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, finite-groups

I would like to   find the irreducible characters of the group $E_8(5)$ (mod 2)?
Can anyone help? (I am elementary in working with Brauer characters)
Many thanks

Comment: What do you mean by the irreducible characters (mod $2$)? Do you mean the Brauer characters in characteristic $2$?

Comment: Yes, I would like to know the Brauer characters of $E_8(5)$ is characteristic $2$.

Comment: I don't think it is very likely that anybody will be able to help you with that!